# GestureDetector inside NativeActivity

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, gesture

I want to use `GestureDetector` inside my `NativeActivity` class but it does not seem to work. Is it possible to use `GestureDetector` in `NativeActivity` apps? My code is like this:

```
public class HollywoodActivity extends android.app.NativeActivity {

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private View.OnTouchListener mGestureListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
            mGestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.i("DEBUG", "*** TOUCH VIEW ***");
                    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            };                                  
    }

    private class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

          @Override
          public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

              Log.i("DEBUG", "FLING" + velocityX + " " + velocityY);
              return true;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
              Log.i("DEBUG", "ON DOWN");
              return true;
          }         
    }
}
```

When I run my app, neither `onTouch()`, nor `onFling()` nor `onDown()` ever get called. Am I missing something obvious here or is it not possible to use `GestureDetector` with `NativeActivity`?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
As it doesn't seem to be possible to intercept MotionEvents on the Java side before
they are passed to the C side, I've now tried it the other way round: Whenever I
get an AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_MOTION on the C side, I'm feeding this to the GestureDetector
on the Java side through JNI like this:

```
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, g_android->activity->clazz, (*env)->GetMethodID(env, globalMyNativeActivityClass, "runGestureDetector", "(JJIIFFFFIFFII)V"), AMotionEvent_getDownTime(event), AMotionEvent_getEventTime(event), AMotionEvent_getAction(event), AMotionEvent_getPointerCount(event), AMotionEvent_getRawX(event, 0), AMotionEvent_getRawY(event, 0), AMotionEvent_getPressure(event, 0), AMotionEvent_getSize(event, 0), AMotionEvent_getMetaState(event), AMotionEvent_getXPrecision(event), AMotionEvent_getYPrecision(event), AInputEvent_getDeviceId(event), AMotionEvent_getEdgeFlags(event));
```

The Java method runGestureDetector() simply does this then:

```
public void runGestureDetector(long downTime, long eventTime, int action, int pointerCount, float x, float y, float pressure, float size, int metaState, float xPrecision, float yPrecision, int deviceId, int edgeFlags) {

    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, pointerCount, x, y, pressure, size, metaState, xPrecision, yPrecision, deviceId, edgeFlags));             
}
```

By doing it this way I'm able to detect some gestures. onDown(), onSingleTap() and onScroll()
come in just fine. What is not working, however, is onFling(). But onFling() is the most
important one for me.

My suspection is that onFling() does not work because it might rely on the historical values
that can be stored in a MotionEvent (every MotionEvent has a historical size with historical
parameters, see android/input.h). However, the obtain() constructor of MotionEvent class does
not allow me to construct a MotionEvent object with historical values.

So is there any way to feed the real MotionEvent that I get on the C side to onTouchEvent() on
the Java side? I can get the historical values through the NDK API but AFAICS it is not possible
to construct a MotionEvent with historical information on the Java side :-(

Any ideas?

Comment: Let's fast-forward 7 years. Did you solve this?

Comment: No, I'm not using `NativeActivity` any longer because it became too limited for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I did **not** test this, and I'm not familiar with `NativeActivity` but as far as I can see, you're not hooking up your `GestureDetector`.
Instead of creating an `OnTouchListener`, try to override your Activity's `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
    Log.i("DEBUG", "*** TOUCH VIEW ***");
    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

This will pass every MotionEvent on your Activity right to your GestureDetector. If you want to catch only MotionEvents on a specific View you can attach your OnTouchListener to it:

```
findViewById(R.id.yourView).setOnTouchListener(mGestureListener);
```

Like I already said, this might only apply to normal Activities, I have no clue how NativeActivities work ...

Anyways, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have mentioned that I already tried overriding onTouchEvent() of my NativeActivity. Although the Android documentation says that NativeActivity inherits the onTouchEvent() method from Activity class, it is never called either. So unfortunately, this is no way to go either :/

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I also would just have commented your question but my reputation doesn't permit this yet. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with C/C++ either, but did you take a look at [onInputQueueCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html#onInputQueueCreated(android.view.InputQueue))?

Comment: Hmm, how do you think could onInputQueueCreated() help here? I somehow need to find a way to intercept all touch events to forward them to GestureDetector. I don't see how onInputQueueCreated() could help here...

Comment: I don't know, it just sounded like a bridge between the programming levels. But having read some more Google-Hits and [SO-Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920454/android-nativeactivity-intercepting-input-at-the-java-level) I'm afraid that you have to catch input events in the underlaying native code because they immediately get passed to it. But as I already said, I'm just shooting in the dark :(